# Change each element of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ruby 1.9

I'm trying to do a trivial operation in Ruby. I want to change each element of array by adding some data to its property title as a prefix.

```
def my_proc
         @data = SomeTable.all
         @data.each { |d| 'my_title___'<< pt.title }
end
```

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**: I need to append some value to `pt.title` as a prefix. If pt.title == "some title" then after appending it must be "my_title___some title". Of course, as a result it must be an array of objects with changed titles.

How do I do that?

Comment: As result you want array of prefixed titles or array of objects with changed titles?

Comment: array of objects with changed titles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
@data.each { |d|  d.title = 'my_title___' + d.title }
```

Answer (score 5):

To return array of objects with changed title use `map` method returning object in block.

```
def my_proc
     @data = SomeTable.all
     @data.map { |d| 
        d.title='my_title___' + pt.title
        d
     }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the map function : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map

```
def my_proc
         @data = SomeTable.all
         @data.map! { |d| 'my_title___'<< pt.title }
end
```

Comment: This won't work as listed; it changes the array of objects into an array of strings (the prefixed titles)

Comment: Must of misread the question. @xdazz answer is therefore the way to go.